# On the h5 page of the mobile terminal, the video screen of ios 17+ is not fully displayed

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, ios17

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uilvj.png)On the h5 page of mobile terminal, there is a problem with the display of the video screen in ios 17+. Has anyone ever encountered this situation? The width and height of the video label is 100%, but only part of the screen inside will [fail], which will be displayed normally in ios16, and the object-fit: contain is set; This style also does not use the h5 page of the mobile terminal. There is a problem with the display of the video screen in ios 17+, has anyone encountered this situation? The width and height of the video label is 100%, but only a part of the screen inside will be displayed normally in ios16, and the object-fit: contain is set; This style doesn't work either

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CRhK.png)

```
<template>
  <div style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <button style="position:fixed;top:10px;left:10px;z-index:3" @click="isChange = !isChange">
      change
    </button>
    <div :style="[isChange ? style1 : style2, { backgroundColor: 'red' }]">
      <video autoplay muted src="xxx" style="width:100%;height:100%"></video>
    </div>
    <div :style="[isChange ? style2 : style1, { backgroundColor: 'blue' }]">
      <video autoplay muted src="xxx" style="width:100%;height:100%"></video>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      style1: { position: 'fixed', top: '0', left: '0', bottom: '0', right: '0', zIndex: 1 },
      style2: {
        position: 'fixed',
        right: '50px',
        top: '50px',
        width: '120px',
        height: '170px',
        zIndex: 2
      },
      isChange: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```